# OpenCV, trying to get maximum and minium of multiple contours

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, tuples

So I am trying to get Max top and lowest points in multiple contours.
It works when I want to find a the top and bottompoint for the biggest contour:

```
c = max(contours, key=cv.contourArea)
extTop = tuple(contours[-1][contours[-1][:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
extBot = tuple(contours[-1][contours[-1][:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
```

Now I try to get the top and bottom point of all the contours together but it doesnt work:

```
extTop = tuple(contours[contours[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
extBot = tuple(contours[contours[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
```

it gives:

```
extTop = tuple(contours[contours[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])

TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Anyone knows a solution? I am prety new to coding so it might be a stupid question, but I have been trying for more than a day now.

Edit:
tried this first, also didnt work:

```
c = max(contours, key=cv.contourArea)
extTop = tuple(contours[-1][contours[-1][:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
extBot = tuple(contours[-1][contours[-1][:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the top and bottom point of each contour, you need to iterate through the tuple containing all the contours.

In the following, we pick one contour `c` from the collection of `contours`. Draw the top and bottom most point:

```
for c in contours:
  top_point = tuple(c[c[:,:,1].argmin()][0])
  bottom_point = tuple(c[c[:,:,1].argmax()][0])
  img = cv2.circle(img, top_point, 6, (255, 255, 0), -1)
  img = cv2.circle(img, bottom_point, 6, (0, 255, 255), -1)
```

**UPDATE:**

The following snippet finds the top-most and bottom-most (Y-coordinate) among **ALL** contours in the image:

```
# initialize an array
cc = np.array([[0, 0]], dtype=int)

# iterate through every contour
for i, c in enumerate(contours):
    # reshape array storing contour boundary points
    c_modified = c.reshape(len(contours[i]), 2)
    # concatenate with initialized array
    cc = np.concatenate((cc, c_modified), axis = 0)

# avoiding first element in the initialized array
new_cc = cc[1:]
```

`new_cc` now contains the boundary coordinates of **ALL** contours.

Use `np.max()` and `np.min()` functions to get desired values:

```
bottom_most = np.max(new_cc[:,1])
top_most = np.min(new_cc[:,1])
```

Comment: It was a good start thanks!
I needed to add a few lines to get the furthest points, and I only care about the Y axis:

        for cont in contours:
            top_point = tuple(cont[cont[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
            bottom_point = tuple(cont[cont[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
            if bottom_point[1] > bottom1[1]:
                bottom1 = bottom_point
            if top_point[1] < top1[1]:
                top1 = top_point

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Change this:

```
extTop = tuple(contours[-1][contours[-1][:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
extBot = tuple(contours[-1][contours[-1][:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
```

to:

```
extTop = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmin()][0])
extBot = tuple(c[c[:, :, 1].argmax()][0])
```

Comment: thanks, it is actually the same. Was using the c first yes but changed it to contours[-1]